# Assigning a minimum value (array.Min()) to an element in an array in a custom method

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

For starters I'm relatively new to C# and this is for a programming 1 class. And this is a console app. I have to use two custom methods to allow the user to enter up to 10 values in an array already assigned EX. `int[] numberArray = new int[10]` This is a computer tested question otherwise I'd have just defined the array and set the length to however many entries the user enters. In the first method you set up the loop to allow the user to input the 10 values, or if the sentinel value of 999 is entered, you exit the loop. The second method displays the statistics of the values entered (amount of values the array holds, the minimum value, the maximum value, the sum of the values, and the average). Here is what I have for the statistic method of which the parameters were predefined for the assignment, and inside is my code:

```
public static void Statistics(int[] array, int els, out int high, out int low, 
    out int sum, out double avg)
{        
    //set statistic values via the arguments
    els = count;
    high = array.Max();
    low = array.Min();
    sum = array.Sum();
    avg = array.Average();
    //output the statistics
    WriteLine("The array has {0} values", els);
    WriteLine("The highest value is {0}", high);
    WriteLine("The lowest value is {0}", low);
    WriteLine("The sum of the values is {0}", sum);
    WriteLine("The average is {0}", avg);
}
```

The problem I'm finding is that even if the user does not enter 10 total values, the minimum is always set to 0. Per my professors advice I have tried using a for loop that iterates the value of count, which is what I use to assign the amount of values entered. When doing this the low variable counts as not being assigned (since it is an out and needs an assigned value). I gather that is due to it being considered a local variable when it is in the for loop. Everything else checks out other than the minimum value being properly assigned so that is my main question and concern is how would I assign it a proper minimum value if the user does not enter in 10 values. If the user does enter 10 values the minimum is correct. As a side note the way I got count to work was by setting it to public and outside of the main() method to allow it to be assigned when inside the for loop and nested if statement for determining if the sentinel value has been entered. 
I mainly think the Statistics method is where my trouble is but here is the code for the other method in case improvements can be made, or perhaps that's where the problem lies.

```
{
    int x;
    string inputString;
    WriteLine("Enter an integer: ");

    for (x = 0; x < array.Length; ++x)
    {
        inputString = ReadLine();
        //Will break the loop to continue to next method or line
        if (int.Parse(inputString) == 999)
        {
            // count how many times we entered in data
            count = x;
            break;
        }
        // will add input to array and continue until sentinel value is entered
        array[x] = int.Parse(inputString);
        WriteLine("Enter another integer: ");
    }

    count = x;
    return x;
}
```

I only added the int = x because the method needed to return an int and I wasn't sure how else to make it work.

Comment: Max(), Min(), Sum(), Average(), are all going to use the full array as declared (10 elements).  Declare a new array with the correct count and pass that as a parameter, or write your own math functions that pay attention to your count variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you haven't shown the code, but where you create your array, of size 10 probablly, will be initizializing that array to 10 things all equal to 0.

If you track the count of how many things you put in that array, you can do

```
array.Take(count).Min();
```

or you can dynamically grow the array ( or ideally, just use a generic list ) as you get each input.  However, depending on your professor, there may be different requirements about what you are allowed to use

Comment: We haven't learned lists yet sadly. And yes it was initializing all values to 0 like you mention. However, this did solve my problem so thank you! Sadly this is graded via a computer from the online part of our textbook. This helped me pass the checks from 65% to 70%. Cengage(the host of the online text) need specific output but this is due to the array.Average(); it looks like.

Comment: cool, if it answers your question, accept the answer as the solution :)